# Why am I getting ERROR: number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm getting an error that says number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement on this line here

```
$query1->bind_result($book_id, $title, $isbn, $isbn13, $pubyear, $pubname);
```

Except I know 100%, for a fact that the procedure returns the fields: book_id, book_title, isbn, isbn13, pubyear, pubname in that order.

Why could I be getting this error?
Here's my full code

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == basename(__FILE__)) {
    header('Location: /spabsa/phprouter');
}
function showBooksByTitle()
{
    include_once '../../blurg.inc';
    # VALIDATE THIS YOU MORON!!
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    
    $db1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'spabsa', $password, 'STUspabsa');
    if($db1->connect_errno > 0)
    {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db1->connect_error . ']');
    }
    
    $query1 = $db1->prepare("call getbooksbytitle(?)");
    $query1->bind_param('s', $title);

    $query1->execute();

    $query1->bind_result($book_id, $title, $isbn, $isbn13, $pubyear, $pubname);

    while($query1->fetch()) {
        echo '<a href="searh/bookinfo/' . $book_id . '">' . $title . '</a><br />';
        echo $pubyear . '<br />';
        echo $pubname . '<br />';
        echo $isbn . '<br />';
        echo $isbn13 . '<br />';
    }

    $query1->free_result();
    $db1->close();
}

showBooksByTitle();
?>
```

here's the procedure

```
delimiter $
create procedure getbooksbytitle(booktitle char(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE searchterm CHAR(201);
    set searchterm = "%";
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(booktitle) > 0 THEN
        set searchterm = concat(booktitle,'%');
        SELECT gb.book_id, gb.title,gb.isbn,gb.isbn13,gb.pubyear,gp.pubname
            FROM grbooks gb
            JOIN grpublishers gp ON (gp.publisher_id=gb.publisher_id)
            WHERE gb.title LIKE searchterm;    
    END IF;
END $
delimiter ;
```

Comment: can you add the stored procedure

Comment: Yah sorry just did

Comment: Looks like you bind just one $query1->bind_param('s', $title)

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical flaw in your Stored Procedure. When `booktitle` is empty then its length will be 0 and your SELECT will never be performed. Stored procedure always returns an empty result even if no SELECT is performed. However, the empty result has no columns so you can't bind to it.

Calling SP from PHP is very cumbersome. You should try to avoid it whenever possible. In your case, the SP has no other logic other than the SELECT, which means you could get rid of SP and call the SELECT using normal prepared statement. But if you wanted to solve the problem of an empty result set then I would probably advice to use `get_result()` rather than binding.

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<a href="searh/bookinfo/' . $row['book_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br />';
        echo $row['pubyear'] . '<br />';
        echo $row['pubname'] . '<br />';
        echo $row['isbn'] . '<br />';
        echo $row['isbn13'] . '<br />';
    }
    $stmt->next_result(); // To consume the empty result
}
```

But I would strongly recommend to redesign the SP or get rid of it completely.